# EPPlus, running in Azure produces "A generic error occurred in GDI+"

Tags: c#, azure, epplus

I'm working with a console application / WebJob which utilises the EPPlus library for working with Excel -files (.xlsx). My application basically opens a set of Workbooks and merges them together as one file.

The application is running fine locally, but not in Azure. According to the `StackTrace` the error happens inside the EEPlus library when trying to save an image (I assume this is done to move images from one Workbook to another).

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ApplicationException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)
at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture..ctor(ExcelDrawings drawings, XmlNode node)
at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawing.GetDrawing(ExcelDrawings drawings, XmlNode node)
at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawings.AddDrawings()
at OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelDrawings..ctor(ExcelPackage xlPackage, ExcelWorksheet sheet)
at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheets.Add(String Name, ExcelWorksheet Copy)
```

The original code, which produces the error open calling `ConvertTo`.

```
Part = drawings.Part.Package.GetPart(UriPic);
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(UriPic.OriginalString);
ContentType = GetContentType(f.Extension);
_image = Image.FromStream(Part.GetStream());
ImageConverter ic=new ImageConverter();
var iby=(byte[])ic.ConvertTo(_image, typeof(byte[]));
var ii = _drawings._package.LoadImage(iby, UriPic, Part);
ImageHash = ii.Hash;
```

After reading several questions on the matter I've tried to modify it using a manual conversion and saving to a `MemoryStream`. However I'm still getting the error.

```
Part = drawings.Part.Package.GetPart(UriPic);
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(UriPic.OriginalString);
ContentType = GetContentType(f.Extension);
_image = Image.FromStream(Part.GetStream());

byte[] iby;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    _image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    iby = ms.ToArray();                
}

var ii = _drawings._package.LoadImage(iby, UriPic, Part);
ImageHash = ii.Hash;
```

I'm really stuck on what to try next. The exception doesn't produce that much to go on, and I feel I've already tried all the suggestions out there: Checking folder and file permissions (my app uses the temp folder, which I believe is safe), avoid reusing streams and so on.

Please let me know if you need any additional information and I'll gladly put it up.

Comment: Running out of memory ought to be your top consideration, this code isn't exactly frugal with it.  A wonky image in the .doc file next.

Comment: Well, do you believe that would be the case in both instances (modified and un-modified)? I can see how my modified example could run that risk, but both examples crash in the exact same manner.

Comment: Well, why not, they both gobble memory and presumably both process the same .xlsx file.  You can't really leave out any details about the specific file this fails on.

Comment: So the excel-files are really small, < 40KB. The images are even smaller, < 5KB (it's just a low res company logo). There are instances when I'm merging up to 50 files, but it always crashes on the first file it tries to merge into the "group" file.

Comment: without really checking it out. We've had a similar problem which has been solved by use `using` where ever streams are in use. The underlying library seems to use data from the streams at a very late point. If the stream is optimized away in the meantime, an exception is raised.

Comment: Hi @KGChristensen, did you find a solution to your issue? I am facing the same issue with a specific excel file - the strange thing is that this occurs only for specific excel files or certain conditions, which I am unable to determine.

Comment: @navigator No, sorry: This error actually popped up again very recently after we changed the template XLSX file for the app in question.

Comment: @KGChristensen, well noted. We managed to locate the error to a specific picture logo embedded in an excel template. We changed the logo, and it worked fine.

Comment: @navigator Heh, yupp - that's how we solved it as well. The replacement template contained an image which, for some reason, threw the Exception. It seems it related to the way epp uses streams when saving (searching for image streams and gdi+ error turns up a few results).

Answer (score 0):

I typically use EPPlus in this way:

1. Grab a template.xlsx I have previously formatted
2. Add data to it (using C# and EPPlus)
3. Return the new xlsx to the user

I recently had the same error:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

**How it was solved:**

My **template.xlsx** was using Excel's **Camera Tool**: that is, there was a snapshot in one of the sheets that was being pasted in another sheet.

This works fine locally (in my computer) but not in Azure... I don't know why.

But if I remove the snapshot it works

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the current versions of EPPlus, due to a dependency on the System.Drawing libraries internally.

See here for an official thread on the topic:
https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/427

And here for some other interesting reading: https://photosauce.net/blog/post/5-reasons-you-should-stop-using-systemdrawing-from-aspnet

It seems like the only way through this will be to identify the functions in EPP that depend on System.Drawing and work around them. Or adjust EPP to use a different library for graphics.

This may be a good start for you to begin determining the parts you can avoid: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/search?q=%22using+system.drawing%3B%22&unscoped_q=%22using+system.drawing%3B%22